# What exactly is navigationController.view.superview?

Tags: objective-c, ios

My project has existing code in several places where it uses `navigationController.view.superview.frame` and `navigationController.view.superview.center` to size and center modal views on top of current view.  Sure I can use them as boiler plates but honestly I have no idea what `navigationController.view.superview` really refers to. Is it particular to `UINavigationControllers`? Any ideas/comments would be appreciated.

[Edit] Here's the code:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = self.storyboard;
MyViewController *vc = (MyViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyLoginViewController"];
vc.delegate= self;
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

navController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(
                                                navController.view.superview.frame.origin.x,
                                                navController.view.superview.frame.origin.y,
                                                400.0f,
                                                400.0f
                                                );
navController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
```

If I don't use navigation controller for the new modal view, I wouldn't have to use "superview".  Namely,

```
UIStoryboard *sb = self.storyboard;
MyViewController *vc = (MyViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyLoginViewController"];
vc.delegate= self;

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(
                                                vc.view.frame.origin.x,
                                                vc.view.frame.origin.y,
                                                400.0f,
                                                400.0f
                                                );
vc.view.center = self.view.center;
```

However, I wouldn't be able to view the presenting vc in the background...

Answer (score 1):

- `navigationController` - This is, well probably a `UINavigationController`. I say probably because you've not given any context so I can only assume that from the name.
- `navigationController.view` - The navigation controller's view.
- `navigationController.view.superview` - The navigation controller's view's superview. i.e. the view that the navigation controller's view sits in.
- `navigationController.view.superview.frame` - The navigation controller's view's superview's frame. i.e. the frame (position and size) of the view the navigation controller's view sits in.
- `navigationController.view.superview.center` - The navigation controller's view's superview's centre. i.e. the centre (position of the centre point) of the view the navigation controller's view sits in.

It's **ugly** to use these properties directly like that. I can't conceive of why you would want to ever go hunting into the depths of the view hierarchy like that to do anything. This to me is a [bad smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). I suggest finding the right way of solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks. That's what the syntax tells me, but I don't understand why it's necessary to address the superview (regardless of whether it's bad taste of ugly). It seems to be navigation controller specific. I can size and center an UIView by simply setting its view's frame and center properties without referencing its superview.   Here's the original code: `

Comment: How the heck do I enter a new line in comments anyway?! -- Guess not.  I'll edit my original post with the code.

Comment: The code looks pretty crazy to me. I wouldn't do that. My point about bad smell stands!

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, that probably refers to your instance of `UIWindow`. If you're trying to center things on screen, you can get the rect of the device's screen using `[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame`.

Comment: This is the type of answer I was hoping - that navController.view.superview transcends to something else; unfortunately, I don't think (per the code newly provided in my question) the new modal view creates another instance of UIWindow/UIScreen -- or does it?!

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [documentation for UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/superview), the method `-superview` returns the view's superview in the view hierarchy. That is, the superview is the view that contains the navigation controller's view. This is not specific to UINavigationController.

Comment: I understand every view can have a superview and in that context, it's certainly not particular to nav controllers.  My question was why I needed to refer to navController's view's superview.